# Testing whether R command has error or not in ifelse command

Tags: r, if-statement

I want to check whether R command has error or not in iflese command. Similar to following one. I wonder how to accomplish this one. Actually I want to run the following code only if there is no error in the previous R code.

```
ifelse(
      test= Check R Command has error or not
    , yes = FALSE
    , no = TRUE
    )


ifelse(
      test= log("a") # Has error
    , yes = 3
    , no = 1
    )
```

Comment: Or `tryCatch({log('a'); 1}, error=function(e) 3)`

Comment: This should be a good read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r

Comment: Thanks @jbaums for your nice comment. Would you like to convert your comment to answer. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `tryCatch` for this:

```
tryCatch({
  log(10)
  1
}, error=function(e) 3)

# [1] 1


tryCatch({
  log('a')
  1
}, error=function(e) 3)

# [1] 3
```

In the second example above, the first expression (which can be multi-line, as above) throws an error, so the expression passed to the `error` argument is executed.